# How to change selectable actions when text is highlighted

Tags: flutter, webview

[image]

The options Translate, Copy and Share are appearing when user long presses in webview.

How can I add my own option or remove one of them.

I guess I have to do changes navitely.

EDIT

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WebViewWidget(
      controller: _controller,
    );
  }
```

Comment: Could you please supply the code that generates this webview?

Comment: I just initialized the _controller in initState() and returned the WebViewWidget

Comment: Do you mean to ask how to change the popup when text is highlighted rather than longpressing on the webview?

Comment: I mean when user long presses kn text the menu popup that appears contains share, copy, translate. In that menu how can I add my own option or modify the existing options.

Comment: I don't think you can. This is the android default as it relates to how text is handled and not your app.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the widget with `Inkwell` and specify `onLongPress:` to trigger code for a popup.